# Does the AV Multiport adapter charge big MacBook Pros?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging, charger

I have a 16 inch MacBook Pro (2019) and if I connect the charging cable through the [USB-C AV Multiport adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter) (USB-A, HDMI, power), my MacBook Pro won't charge.

Is this expected behaviour? The product page does not say anything.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that you can see in About This Mac > System Report > Power

If the power cable is connected to the MacBook Pro directly:

```
AC Charger Information:

  Connected:    Yes
  ID:   0x7002
  Wattage (W):  94
  Name: 96W USB-C Power Adapter
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Charging: Yes
```

and if it's connected through the Multiport adapter:

```
AC Charger Information:

  Connected:    Yes
  ID:   0x7002
  Wattage (W):  55
  Name: 96W USB-C Power Adapter
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Charging: No
```

So if it's looped through the adapter it's only getting 55W which is not enough for the big laptop to charge.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I connect my 13" 2017 MBP to an Apple 61W charger.

Directly connected I see:

[image]

Through the DMPA I see:

[image]

I cannot find anything in Apple documentation to indicate that this is expected.

The only thing which tangentially touches on this is this note from the
[data sheet on the DMPA](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207806):

> Because this adapter draws power from your Mac or iPad Pro even when your Mac or iPad Pro is asleep, you might want to unplug it when it's not also connected to power for charging.

But this is only when the DMPA is connected to the device without the power cable connected. I tried this on three DMPA's with the same result.

**EDIT**: We are not alone in these observations:

Apple [Community Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251558969)
[MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/2016-macbook-pro-15-tb-only-charges-at-55w-when-connected-via-digital-av-adapter.2033692/)

From [this page at Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700) the choice of cable is important, too:

> Make sure you're using the correct USB-C charge cable
> For the best charging experience, you should use the USB-C charge cable that comes with your Mac notebook. If you use a higher wattage USB-C cable, your Mac will still charge normally. USB-C cables rated for 29W or 30W will work with any USB-C power adapter, but won't provide enough power when connected to a power adapter that is more than 61W, such as the 96W USB-C Power Adapter.

The cable I'm using is not Apple branded (the MBP I use was a former loaner laptop where I work) and I just picked a charger and cable from another bin of spares.

Comment: DMPA = Digital MultiPort Adapter?

Comment: It's super weird that this isn't documented and because I only used 13" computers up until now I never ran into this issue.